# Change icon of all running forms

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I have got 3 forms and on one of them there is a button which is supposed to change icons of all my running forms.

I cannot figure out how to change the icon on the other two forms, I have managed to do so on just one form (where the button is located).

I have tried this way:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Form f2 = new Form2();
        f1.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
        f2.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
    }
```

... but had no success.

Basically, I am stuck here now, since the code above doesn't work for me:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `OpenForms` collection in the `Application` class to iterate over all the open Forms and set the `Icon`

Example:

```
foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
{
    form.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple; 
}
```

Comment: Might include that `using System.Linq;` is required to use `.Cast` (when I tested in .NET 3.5 anyways).

Comment: @making3, Thanks, I do forget about the older frameworks sometimes :), Your comment should be enough info for OP if he is using 3.5, I think in .Net4-4.5 `using System.Linq` is added by default to all classes

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you very much! I am using 4.5 so there was no need to add `using System.Linq`.